# Why don't we count CPU operations?

Tags: performance, performance-tools

When evaluating code performance, CPU instructions is not the best metric, since the exact number of operations depends on the compiler, CPU model, architecture and so on.

And we came up with a bunch of mathematical tools to describe the performance of an algorithm (the most popular being big-Oh notation) and we simply report the running time to get a feel for how the implementation runs in practice (yes, big-Oh is not always that easy to use).

I need to optimize a piece of code. This implies a lot of reading and staring at the code looking for places to improve, but also a great deal of experimentation. I need to check if idea A does improve (and by how much) the performance. And I do this by measuring the time it takes to execute a piece of code.

But this is quite imperfect: I do use a multitasking system. I cannot totally reproduce the running conditions of the previous experiment. My browser might decide to start 10 more threads which get in the way, or I might get some CPU throttling at a different point in time due to various reasons.

So, usually, I need not only to wait for my program to run, but I also tend to close my browser, make sure the IDE is not indexing or doing some expensive operation, wait a few minutes for the CPU to cool down, and then run my experiment. This is the only way I could get reliable timings.

The question is: is there a way to count the number of operations? On my CPU, for a specific process. This would be (theoretically) an ideal way of comparing 2 versions of my code, unless there is some issue I am missing.

Comment: I am puzzled - first you say that counting CPU instructions is probably not the most sensible metrics, but then you ask for exactly that - a method for counting CPU instructions. So what?

Comment: ... but have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568557/how-to-count-the-total-number-of-cpu-cycles-and-instructions-retired-during/42568698) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/how-to-get-the-cpu-cycle-count-in-x86-64-from-c), there are tools for counting CPU cycles and instructions. Found those by simply googling "count cpu cycles".

Comment: @DocBrown I am aware of some ways. But it doesn't seem to be a very common benchmark, and there don't seem to be much tools that support it. Which made me wonder if there is something wrong with this methodology.

Comment: That's probably why profilers are the tool of choice.

Comment: Given the fact there are several tools which support CPU cycle count, I don't see why you think "doesn't seem to be a very common benchmark". And you did not answer my first question.

Comment: Sometimes we do.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is a *Profiler*.

Most IDEs include this functionality; if activated, it compiles a special version of the code that is able to tell you pretty exactly how much time is spent in which code line. You can analyze this, and then you know where exactly the CPU effort is spent.

The strategy you describe is very inefficient, it's like closing your eyes and shooting in the forest, and hoping to hit a deer.

Comment: I do use a profiler sometimes, and it's great for getting an overview of the most expensive pieces of code. But (and correct me if I'm wrong), a profiler is still affected by CPU throttling (or lower CPU frequency, in general).

Comment: it would depend on the profiler, but that rarely is relevant, as almost always, 90%+ is spent in one place in the code, and that's all you need to know - three valid digits in that percentage don't give you anything.

Comment: Well, that's what i am actually interested in - if a certain piece of code runs 1-2% faster or not after a change, not which part is the most expensive.

Comment: @Paul92 If you think CPU throttling is an issue, you can change your system settings to disable that feature, so it is always running at top speed.

Comment: @Paul92: then you are doing it wrong. Which part is the most expensive is pretty much the *only* thing you should be interested in, because that is where you can really make the code run faster. Looking at 1-2% differences is a useless waste of time unless you work on code that runs on thousands of servers *and* have already identified that code as the most expensive.

Answer (score 2):

To give some examples why this is not very feasible. Modern processors work on quite a few instructions at a time, but only if the instructions are independent. The processor will try to guess any branches in the code, and there can be a huge difference if it guesses correctly or not. Loading a memory address might be at almost no cost if it is cached, ~200 cycles if it is fetched from main memory, or a lot more if the memory has been paged to disk. Because of this the time to execute one instruction might vary a huge amount, so simply counting the number of exectuted instructions will tell you very little about the actual performance.

Quite a bit about performance optimization has to do with efficiently using the processors we have, and this includes efficient memory access, branches that can be predicted and instructions that may be executed concurrently whenever possible. So the only feasible solution is to measure the actual time.

There are a many different profilers that can help reveal potential bottlenecks. [Intel VTune](https://software.intel.com/vtune) claims to be able to provide data down to instruction level, including pipeline stalls, but I have no personal experience with this.

[High resolution timestamps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps) provide a high frequency counter that is used to measure performance. If you only want the time spent executing a particular thread the only way I know of would be to stop/start the timer when the thread is switched in or out. I would expect most profilers should be able to do this for you. Here is some information about how [dotTrace measures time](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__Setting_the_Right_Meter_Kind.html#).

Comment: I am aware of the pipelining and branch prediction issues, but I assume they are deterministic. But your post made me understand an issue: even if you count CPU cycles (this is what I actually meant by instruction, not ASM instruction), you can't get total isolation since other processes running might create cache misses.

Comment: Pipelining and branch prediction might be mostly deterministic for a given processor model, but certainly not for different models. What I guess you are after is "Thread Time" i.e. how much time the processor spend executing a particular thread. Updated the answer with some more info about this.

Comment: As well as time, you can often *actually count* things like mispredicted branches.

Answer (score 1):

Your only choice is to run the same piece of code numerous (aka 1000s of) times and collect statistics.

I would recommend setting up a computer as a test-rig to do this. If that isn't possible you will need to use your own - just stop waiting for the cpu to clear.

Your code in a production environment is not going to get the benefit of a cold CPU, or a light workload. It will be competing with the other processes, and those other processes will be utilising resources and will have an effect on the algorithms total runtime.

A well tuned algorithm may use a slightly slower path (for a single app experience), that is faster overall when there is load on the system. The reason will be down to utilisation of bandwidth which increases latency (hence a generally slower end-to-end timing than a low latency approach on quiet hardware), but will achieve a higher throughput (hence completing more work with the allocated resources, and reducing overall runtime on busy hardware).

Comment: I agree that the system will not run in ideal conditions, but the point was not to benchmark the system, but to get a reliable measure of the difference in performance between 2 versions of the code. That is also my point with the CPU frequency scaling and multithreading: these aspects make the comparison harder to obtain, especially if we're talking about many small optimizations.

Comment: @Paul92, if you care about small differences in speed (1-2% as you indicate in another comment), then you must run each version of the code enough times to ensure that environmental effects can be filtered out of the measurements using statistics.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I agree, and I've been doing exactly that. But my question was asking more for why don't we use a metric like CPU cycles, which would provide a more reliable comparative measurement (at least from my current understanding, which might be flawed).

Comment: @Paul92, with a modern CPU, CPU cycles are also deceptive. How many CPU cycles are used if a branch instruction needs 10 cycles to fetch the information needed to do the comparison, and during 8 of those the branch predictor executes 2 other instructions on a branch that happens to be successfully predicted. Is that 10 or 18 cycles?

Comment: @Paul92 Consider the memory read operation (even just for the code itself), is that serviced by L1, L2, L3 cache? Is it a RAM access? Is it paged out to Disk? How many instructions are executing looking for the page itself? Is it in the look-aside table? Do we have to instead perform an OS level mapping operation? Are we considering micro-code instructions or are we talking a high-level machine language instruction? Unless you have the increasingly rare case of a CPU bound algorithm, instruction counting isn't even useful as it can be considered instantaneous, compared to the time taken by IO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows .NET and you want to do this yourself, have a look at class System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread.

If you obtain this for a particular thread you can inspect properties TotalProcessorTime, UserProcessorTime and PrivilegedProcessorTime. This should tell you what you need to know.

Get a hold of them like this:

```
ProcessThreadCollection threadCollection = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;

foreach (ProcessThread processThread in threadCollection)
{
    // have your way with them
}
```